# How to check which hexadecimal numbers are within a range expressed by hexadecimal numbers?

Tags: python, compare, hex, string-comparison

I have a list of hexadecimal numbers and I want to find what of thi number are within a specific range, **without the use of range python function**.

The list of hexadecimal number is the following:

```
h = ["00000100", "000000c0", "000000a0" "00000620", "00000660", "00006000"]
```

I want to find numbers which are greater than `"00000100"` and less than `"00000610"` in python.

So how can I do it?

I have tried with the following code:

```
h = ["00000100", "000000c0", "000000a0" "00000620", "00000660", "00006000"]
num = 
for i in h:
    if i >="00000100"and <= "00000610":
        print(i)
```

Comment: can you try that, 

    if int(i, 16)  >= int("00000100", 16) and i <= int("00000610", 16)

You must convert to integer from hexadecimal

Comment: actually it probably works if you keep the zero padding

Comment: What about your current approach isn't working? If all of your strings have the same length and the letters `a..f` have the same casing in all of them, it should work fine with your current approach (if you add the missing `i` in your second `<= ` comparison)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  Even with your assumption you need  `"00000100" <= i <= "00000610"`

Comment: @derpirscher Even with your assumption you need `"00000100" <= i <= "00000610"`

Comment: @Booboo Yeah, just noticed, and adapted my comment ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `int` built-in function can convert a string in any base:

```py
h = ["00000100", "000000c0", "000000a0" "00000620", "00000660", "00006000"]

for s in h:
    if int("00000100", 16) <= int(s, 16) <= int("00000610", 16):
        print(s)
```

Prints:

```None
00000100
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if all the elements are of same length as posted by OP. If values are of variables length then we can convert them using `int()` as posted by @Booboo

```
h = ["00000100", "000000c0", "000000a0" "00000620", "00000660", "00006000"] 
for i in h:
    if i >="00000100"and i<= "00000610":
        print(i)
#output
00000100
```

oneliner List comp:

```
[i for i in h if i >="00000100"and i<= "00000610"]
["00000100"]
```

Comment: How would this do if one of the elements of `h` were "110'? Your solution works because you are assuming (perhaps correctly) that all elements of `h` will be the same length.

Comment: @Booboo you are right, it will only work when all the elements are of same length. I will put is in the edit.